# How to populate text string in listview in defined intervals in android?

Tags: java, android

I got stuck in one problem, I want to populate my string values from List in Listview after every 3 seconds. I wrote the below code but it gives me all my text at single shot after 9 seconds which means after completing the task.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    ArrayList<String> list;
    ListView listview;
    ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        list = new ArrayList<String>();

        list.add("1");
        listAdapter();
        try {

            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        list.add("2");
        listAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);

        listAdapter();
        try {

            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        list.add("3");
        listAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);

        listAdapter();
        try {

            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void listAdapter() {

        listview.invalidateViews();
        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listadapter, list);
        // put adapter in list view
        listview.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        listAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
    }
```

Comment: use notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: I used it but text 1,2,3 are displaying after 9 seconds only.:(

Comment: Okay providing you the answer

Comment: what exactly you want to do ?

Comment: I want to display 1,2,3 in listview in the interval of 3 seconds in each. for eg. in list view first it should display 1 then after 3 seconds should display 2 and finally 3 after three seconds.

Answer (score 1):

TimerTask  - is your answer. form the look of the code you block UI thread for 9 seconds.

it should help. http://android-er.blogspot.com/2013/12/example-of-using-timer-and-timertask-on.html

or this: http://android.okhelp.cz/timer-simple-timertask-java-android-example/

Comment: @ alpha started your service in StackOverflow with a good answer.Go ahead.

Comment: I tried with this. It didnt work. Can you provide any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one. It is working.

Put this in Oncreate

```
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(hourlyTask, 0l, 3000);
```

Put this outside oncreate

```
    TimerTask hourlyTask = new TimerTask() {

    public void run() {

        hand.sendEmptyMessage(1);

      }
   };

@SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
Handler hand = new Handler() {

    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
        if (msg.what == 1) {

            arrlist.add("1");
            arrlist.add("2");
            arrlist.add("3");

            ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

            ListviewAdapter adapter = new ListviewAdapter(Sample.this,
                    arrlist);
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);

        }

    }

};
```

Comment: can you tell me what do you mean by 'keep outside the oncreate method'?

Comment: After the end of OnCreate Override method.  @Override ... Oncreate...{ ..} //here enter  that code

Answer (score 0):

if Thread.sleep() called in main Thread it causes to freeze the UI,  so always use Sleep() in background thread, this should work in your case , I didn't tried it but

```
void updateListView(final Activity act, final String[] itemsToAdd, ArrayList<String> list, final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < itemsToAdd.length; i++)
            {
                list.add(itemsToAdd[i]);
                new Thread(new Runnable()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void run()
                            {
                                try
                                    {
                                        Thread.sleep(3000);
                                    }
                                catch (InterruptedException e)
                                    {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                act.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                                    {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run()
                                            {
                                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                            }
                                    });
                            }
                    }).start();
            }
```

Comment: tell me the parameter you're passing to this method ?